# .htaccess internal server error if upload_max_filesize added

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, internal-server-error, apache2.4

With this code my wordpress website works:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>



# END WordPress
```

But with this code I get a 500 Internal server error:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300



# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And I tried this too:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is the message I get when I try to access the website:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@myWebsite.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Does anybody have an advice?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it and tell if it works

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 - You were right. The answer was there. I created a .user.ini file in the folder wp-admin, added the settings and it works. Can you please mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: I already did. Moderators have to look at it though